# How to embed calendar in monthly view inside our layout

Tags: android, android-layout, view, calendar, android-activity

I need to embed the native month-wise calendar with my xml layout, which will also contain some other components inside the layout.. it should also show all the calendar events  shown for the specific month. Since i am a beginner in android, any source or example will be very useful !!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

In your case I think you have to use [Datepicker](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html), just go throgth this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/)

Answer (score 1):

Haha, funny how I am currently doing just this. There is no built in view to do this, and even fewer examples of any specific code. You will need to build one from scratch. Luckily, Android does come built in with a class to help with the calculations that would otherwise be very annoying:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/MonthDisplayHelper.html

What does this mean? Well you need to use your own code to build it out. If you have Java experience, should not be too bad just playing around with the dates and whatnot and add them into a table or grid layout (Layouts you should probably go with). As soon as you get the hang of it, then you can get into more complex features.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a grid view and fill according to month array with date-time picker you can get a specific date and time each cell click you can show a list which would help user to make reminder or add note specific to that selected date.

Comment: this is what i want, is there any sample or example code which could help me out?